# How to use the Spotify API and the Spotify SDK

Tags: android, api, authentication, sdk, spotify

I'm making an Android app which uses the Spotify SDK. The user connects to Spotify with the SDK. I want to get the users library, wich is not possible with the SDK. Therefore you must use the API. How can I get user information to give to the API? Or how can I let the user login to the API and the SDK?

I have already searched on the internet and looked into the methods of the SDK.

Answer (score 0):

When you use the Android SDK to authorize a user with the app, you can ask for additional scopes that will help you use the API. You can find a [list of scopes](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/scopes/) that you can then pass along to `setScopes` in your Android app. Spotify will handle the authentication based on the scopes by showing the user an app consent screen.

Authorizing with the correct scopes and the Android SDK will return an access token that can be used for the Web API as well. From there, you can send [API requests to the Web API](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/) to retrieve other user information.